# new tab opening each time i open a link in android application

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have an android application which leads to my company website when the application is opened. I always make it open in  android Google chrome, Each time i call this code a new tab is created in Google chrome. Is there any method to prevent the creation of new tab. The code used to open Google chrome is as follows

```
  Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
  i.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString
  ("com.android.chrome/com.android.chrome.Main"));
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
i.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

Thank you for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [post](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/how-to-view-webpage-inside-your-android.html), I finally found the solution. Here is the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```